# How can i update some attributes of my object?

Tags: javascript

I have a object with many attributes but i want to update only three of them
so far i am updating like this:

```
  local.primary = (local.primary).toFixed(3)
  local.second = local.second.toFixed(3)
  local.last =local.last.toFixed(3)
```

are there any better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be DRY you could use `Object.fromEntries` and map over an array of the properties to change:

```
Object.assign(
  local,
  Object.fromEntries(
    ['primary', 'second', 'last'].map(
      prop => [prop, local[prop].toFixed(3)]
    )
  )
);
```

If you really wanted to spread, I suppose you could do it if reassigning the object or creating a new one is OK:

```
const newObj = {
  ...local,
  ...Object.fromEntries(
    ['primary', 'second', 'last'].map(
      prop => [prop, local[prop].toFixed(3)]
    )
  )
};
```

But if there are only 3 properties, I don't think listing them individually is bad at all:

```
Object.assign(
  local,
  {
    primary: local.primary.toFixed(3),
    second: local.second.toFixed(3),
    last: local.last.toFixed(3),
  }
);
```

It's not clear what the whole data structure is, but `primary`, `second`, and `last` might be better off as their own standalone property object or array.